# Images not showing in iOS 7.1 with XCode 6 / Swift

Tags: xcode, ios7, swift

I have this ObjC code:

```
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-button", self.myObject.name]]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This works great with these combinations:

- XCode 5, iOS 7.1
- XCode 6, iOS 7.1
- XCode 6, iOS 8

But when I port one single class of the project to Swift -- a class which is unrelated to anything that is happening in this code -- the images do not display in XCode 6 for iOS 7.1.  It does work with XCode 6 and iOS 8.

I finished porting the entire project to Swift, so now the code looks like:

```
self.myButton.setBackgroundImage(
    UIImage(named:self.myObject.name + "-button"),
    forState: UIControlState.Normal
)
```

And it's still unhappy on iOS 7.1.  Still no images.  (The custom icon works, though.)  Yes, I know this is just beta software, and it's probably just a bug ... ?  But I'm just wondering if anyone has a solution or insight.

I only started using XCode and ObjC about a week ago (surprise!  ObjC is now deprecated!), so it could be that I am missing something, but since it works in ObjC, and in Swift+iOS8, it seems like it's probably a bug.

Comment: try adding the extension at the end of the image name. I've seen that fix a few issues with Swift code...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, will keep you updated when I figure it out.

Comment: Who said that Objective-C is deprecated?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: Objective-C is not deprecated, you just have two different options you code your iOS/OSX apps in now.

Comment: Same problem here. Looks like assets outside the images bundle still work. I might write a script to copy everything out of the bundle and maintain proper names if we aren't able to come up with any other fix.

Comment: the Objective-C says _"Thank you, I'm still very fine, I'm not deprecated at all!"_.

Comment: Pascal was never actually deprecated on Mac OS, either, was it?

I didn't mean it literally.  But the writing's on the wall.  It'll take some years, but at some point, no one will be doing new development in ObjC.

Comment: You should award the answer to mvcm - his answer is working in beta 3 and probably in the other broken releases. [Note: he could use the points!]

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to overcome this by **not using** Asset Libraries to store my images.

Add your images to the project using the "old style naming", like *Image.png* and *Image@2x.png*, then load them without any extensions in the filename, as such:

```
let myImage = UIImage(named:"Image")
```

Comment: Only solution I've found as well

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in [XCode 6 beta 2](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

> Images from asset catalogs in projects with a minimum deployment target of iOS 7 or OS X 
>   10.9 will be available when running on iOS 8 and OS X 10.10, and now also iOS 7 and OS X 
>   10.9. (17029658)

[release xcode 6 beta 2 notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_2_i8z2ly/xcode_6_beta_2_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: Perfect! Just downloaded XCode 6 Beta 2, added my PNGs to the Asset Catalog, used the image in my buttons, and everything appeared correctly on my iOS 7 device.

Comment: iOS 8 simulator with Xcode 6 beta 2 still does not work, but on iOS7 simulator Xcode 6 beta 2 works

Comment: All of them (iOS 7, iOS 7.1, iOS 8) work for me in XCode 6 Beta 2. Try to create new project and test it there.

Comment: Broken in Xocde 6 beta 6

Comment: Wont the images work if png files are not added to Assets catalog?

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because I suddenly add **jpg** image to *Image Assets*. Just resaved it as **png** and all work well

Comment: Ridiculous.  I did the same thing and it worked.  Seems like a bug?  Or do they only want PNG files used?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are testing it on simulator. Make sure the desired image is copied to 7.1 bundle. To do it check `copy resources bundle` build stage or check manually app bundles for different simulators at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`.

Comment: Actually it is both on the 7.1 simulator, and on my 7.1 device.  But checking what you said now ...

Comment: I look in the main project window and see Copy Bundle Resources, and Images.xcassets is there.  It'd have to be, right, or else it wouldn't show in iOS 8?

I do see an Assets.car in both the iOS 7.1 and iOS 8 devices, and it's the exact same file (checked md5).  So that doesn't seem to be the issue.

And apparently in XCode 6, it's in

  ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_ID/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/APP_ID/APP_NAME.app/

for iOS 8, and

  ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_ID/data/Applications/APP_ID/APP_NAME.app/ for iOS 7.1.)

Answer (score 1):

[@o KB o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776163/o-kb-o) points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173098/163827) that the [Xcode6 Beta release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2014/xcode_6_beta_ie8g3n/xcode_6_beta__release_notes.pdf) mention that `xcassets` bundles aren't supported for iOS7. Additionally, I've found it surprisingly hard to get rid of asset bundles in your project. This can cause naming collisions if your images have the same name as images that were previously in the bundle (you probably want the same names, so you don't have to rename your images everywhere in code / IB).

Here's a workaround:

1. Copy each image out of your `.xcassets` image bundle to a new directory (let's call it `Images/`). See below for a script to make this easier.
2. Delete your `.xcassets` bundle. (surprisingly, *removing it from the project isn't enough*. In my testing, if the `.xcassets` bundle was anywhere in the same directory as the Xcode project or related sources, it would get copied in. Alternately, you can remove the `.xcassets` extension)
3. Add all your image files to your Xcode project
4. Clean (cmd + shift + k)
5. Delete the app from the target device or simulator
6. Install and run

To make step #1 less tedious, I wrote a script to copy images out of the `.xcassets` bundle and into a directory of your choice: https://github.com/johnboiles/xcasset_exporter

```
mkdir Images
./xcasset_exporter.py MyProject/Images.xcassets Images
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where *some* images in xcassets worked and others didn't (only for iOS 7.1).
I solved it by deleting the problematic image sets and creating new ones with different names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to use an ***external bundle*** with proper PNG images stored in either an "old style" folder or inside xcassets then apps running on iOS 7 will **not** be able to access these images.

I tried a suggestion from another answer here to add the "old style" folder path of the images in the external bundle but that didn't work for me. My solution, which fit my scenario, was to expose an outlet for the resource in the nib inside the external bundle. This allowed the main app to set with an accessible image to it. Whether this is a bug or simply a constraint in using nibs contained in external bundles with iOS 7 will matter less as it rides on to the usage sunset...

**PS:** Apps running on iOS 8 where able to access images in the external bundle xcassets just fine so choose your poison for supporting iOS 7.