# Can't change UITabBarItem.image: Unsupported pixel format in CSI

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change through code the image shown in the tab bar. I'm currently working with Swift and Xcode 6 beta 3. I imported my tabBarImage.png and tabBarImage@2x.png in the Images.xcassets and in the AppDelegate I wrote this:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

    let mainColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 91.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = mainColor

    let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
    var tabBarSubcontrollers = tabBarController.viewControllers as [UIViewController]

    let tabBarImages = ["tabBarImageOne", "tabBarImageTwo", "tabBarImageThree"]

    for index in 0..<(tabBarSubcontrollers.count) {
        let tabBarImage = UIImage(named: "\(tabBarImages[index])").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        let newTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: tabBarImage, selectedImage: tabBarImage)
        newTabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0)
        tabBarSubcontrollers[index].tabBarItem = newTabBarItem
    }

    return true
}
```

If i run it on the simulator it works just fine and shows the images in the tab bar. If I run it on my iPad (with iOS 7.1.1), it doesn't load the images and shows this bizarre error:

```
 Unsupported pixel format in CSI
 Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data.
```

Any ideas? Could it be some sort of bug? And what is CSI bitmap data anyway?

Comment: I have the same problem, and this is the only thing I can find that even mentions the error message. Sounds like it could be a new bug?

Comment: And here. All the PNG images that worked fine with Beta 2 suddenly bork.

Comment: I just noticed a new "All" item in the image setup for the asset library. I have a feeling that may have something to do with it...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, currently downloading beta 2 again (http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_2_i8z2ly/xcode_6_beta_2.dmg).

Comment: Nope. Dead end. The "All" thing appeared in all my (many) image assets, but goes away if I re-create them. However, that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. I am rather miffed at Apple. They broke Swift in Beta 3.

Comment: Well, I was able to reproduce it in a simple "Hello World" project, but Apple's bug reporting system seems to have, er, bugs... I'll report it when they get back up.

Comment: Is there a way to "add" oneself to an apple bug? I can't understand why they don't open that up like facebook does (and others) so that people know it is already reported and also can sum to a bug to give more priority

Comment: I suspect that reporting a new one, and referencing another bug report will do that. My RADAR Report is #17594830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grr.

It seems to be an iOS 7 issue. It works in iOS 8.

Beta 2 generated iOS 7 stuff; no problem.

Beta 3 seems to be geared towards iOS 8 only.

I suspect folks trying Swift on iOS 7 are S.O.L.

I have a project that I'll upload to my server that you can mess with.

**UPDATE:** [here's the test project](http://junk.magshare.net/ImageAssetBug.zip)

**UPDATE 2 (July 21, 2014):** This bug appears to be fixed in Xcode 6 beta 4.

However, Swift seems to be a rather quickly moving target...

Comment: It's a problem in iOS 7 with plain old objective-c too. I'm pretty sure it's a beta 3 problem

Comment: Thanks! I would have discovered that when I tried running one of my other apps. I also found [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063778/images-not-showing-in-ios-7-1-with-xcode-6-swift), which leads me to believe it has been a problem before. ALL asset library images are affected; including ones loaded in the storyboard. They show up in the storyboard, but not in the runtime app.

Comment: I do not have any Swift Code in my project but its still crashed with iOS 7. Absolutely beta 3 bug.