# Xcode 6 (beta 3): Unsupported pixel format in CSI or Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data

Tags: ios7, uiimage, swift, xcode6

When loading UIImages with png images in Xcode 6 beta 3 in Swift as follows:

```
    PipsImg = (UIImage(named: "Die-1"))
```

or

```
    PipsImg = [(UIImage(named: "Die-1")),(UIImage(named: "Die-2"))]
```

from associated images stored in the Images.xcassets folder,  I receive the following fatal runtime errors:

```
 SimpleAnimation[680:60b] Unsupported pixel format in CSI
 SimpleAnimation[680:60b] Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data.
```

*this appears to be resolved in beta 4, however will leave in place for a bit as sometimes these regress*

Comment: Those aren't fatal errors, the program keeps running, although those images don't get displayed.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - questions about beta software are still worth answering, who knows if or when it will be fixed or become obsolete ([see discussion on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258515/1693173))

Comment: Makes sense. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks

Comment: I still got the bug in 6.1 ...

Comment: I still got the bug in 6.2 ...

Comment: I sent a bug report to Apple; waiting for a response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change UITabBarItem.image: Unsupported pixel format in CSI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637916/cant-change-uitabbaritem-image-unsupported-pixel-format-in-csi)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Xcode 6 (beta 3 at this time).   It appears to occur only if your build target is iOS 7.x

To work around this issue:

1) delete the files from the Images.xcassets container.

2)  place the images directly into the "Supporting Files" folder.

Note:  It is not required to add the ".png" extension within your code, making this a clean workaround.

Please create a RADAR (bug report) to Apple.

Comment: If you continue to get the same errors as the original post then you need to go to your Organizer (under the Window menu) and delete the derived data.

Comment: This is ridiculous, messes up the projects. I'll just wait for the next Beta.

Comment: This *bug* seems to be fixed in beta 4

Comment: I'm currently running beta 5 and just ran into this issue again.  It would also appear that the workaround does not work for me either.  Anyone have a Radar id I can reference when I file my own?

Comment: Xcode 6.1.1 and iPad running iOS7.1 suffers from this also.

Comment: Xcode 6.1.1 and iPod running iOS7.x suffers from this also.

Comment: Yes you are right @DaRk-_-D0G it seems image.xcassests  having problem with JPG extension.

Comment: @Kamarshad image.xcassests just give PNG, Tiff

Comment: Actully I am using Xcode 6.1.1 with iPhone 5C running iOS 7.0.5 and its crashing so It may not just be related

Comment: I'm in Xcode 7.1.  This works building for iOS 9, but fails building for iOS 8.

Answer (score 23):

XCode 6.0.1 still have this problem.
If you add .jpg to Images.xcassets and try to install app to the iOS 7 device.

To fix it just convert .jpg to .png

Comment: XCode 6.1 also has it but when I converted jpg to png there was no problem. Always using png on xcassets and I accidentally included 2 jpg files and had this issue. It definitely is an issue of xcassets with jpg files.

Answer (score 17):

**Apple engineer's response:**

The issue is that iOS 7 apps cannot have JPEG images in the CAR file. actool should have copied the JPEG as a loose image into your app's folder. To work around this issue, you should either convert the image to a PNG or include the JPEG as a resource outside of the asset catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem via:

1. Run iOS Simulator
2. Reset content and settings via "iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings" menu.
3. It works.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode we now have a possibility to do a slicing for the image resources. If slicing is added the corresponding json for an image in asset catalog gets resizing info. This may look for example like this

```
"resizing" : {
    "mode" : "3-part-vertical",
    "center" : {
      "mode" : "fill",
      "height" : 6
    },
    "capInsets" : {
      "top" : 16,
      "bottom" : 6
    }
  }
```

iOS 7.0 doesn't handle slicing properly. So removing the slicing info from json may help to fix the problem (in my case that was a solution).