# Xcode 6.4 can't create UIImage instance from .xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcasset

After update OS X to El Capitain Xcode can't create build correctly. After start app crashes when try create UIImage instance

```
UIImage(named: "icon_back");
```

and get an error in console

```
[CUIThemeRendition newImageFromCSIDataSlice:ofBitmap: usingColorspace:] Unsupported pixel format in CSI got 4
```

Xcode - Version 6.4
Target iOS version - 7.0
OS X version - El Capitain

### Update

I don't like this solution, but after Xcode reinstall this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Update to Xcode 7.1, please. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911627/image-resources-xcassets-not-displayed-correctly-on-yosemite-in-application-bu

Comment: Do see the question matt linked above, [image resources (xcassets) not displayed properly...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911627/image-resources-xcassets-not-displayed-correctly-on-yosemite-in-application-bu) - though it's not identical to yours. Some people found that converting their .png image assets to .jpg fixed their problem. You might try that...

Comment: @matt Can't update to 7.1, because my project is written on swift 1.2. Xcode 7.1 want move it to swift 2

Comment: Swift 2 is much better and fixes many bugs.

Comment: Xcode will automatically update your code for you.